# android linkedIn integration- acces token not received

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate my app with LinkedIn, but I'm not getting an access code.

```
 LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthSuccess() {

                    Log.e("LinkedIn", "User Loged in");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success" + LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext().getSession().getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();</p>
                    String authToken = LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString();
                    Log.e("LinkedIn auth token", authToken);

                    shareLinkedInContent();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                    // Handle authentication errors
                    Log.e("LinkedIn", error.toString());
                }
            }, true); 




         private void shareLinkedInContent() {

        String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";
        Log.e("LinkedIn", "Posted" + url);
        try {
            JSONObject body = new JSONObject("{" +
                    "\"comment\": \"Sample share\"," +
                    "\"visibility\": { \"code\": \"anyone\" }," +
                    "\"content\": { " +
                    "\"title\": \"Sample share\"," +
                    "\"description\": \"Testing the mobile SDK call wrapper!\"," +
                    "\"submitted-url\": \"http://www.example.com/\"," +
                    "\"submitted-image-url\": \"http://www.example.com/pic.jpg\"" +
                    "}" +
                    "}");
            Log.e("LinkedIn", "Posted" + url);

            APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            apiHelper.postRequest(this, url, body, new ApiListener() {
                @Override
                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                    // Success!
                    Log.e("LinkedIn post success", "Posted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
                    Log.e("LinkedIn post error", liApiError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I get an auth token like `{"expiresOn":0}` and share section gives "access token is not set"

I used the latest LinkedId SDK from [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk).

Comment: Mobile SDK appears depreciated. See https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SDK has been deprecated, in March 1 the APIv1 will be delete.

[Please see](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates)

[Also you can see the migration guide on his official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Answer (score 0):

I created a small library to implement LinkedIn Authentication via OAuth2 because, LinkedIn Mobile SDK Has been deprecated

*Library - https://github.com/Sumudu-Sahan/LinkedInManager*

**Steps**

1. Add the below maven dependency to your project level `build.gradle` file

   `allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
       }
   }`
2. add the below maven dependency to your app level `build.gradle` file

   `dependencies {
           implementation 'com.github.Sumudu-Sahan:LinkedInManager:1.00.02'
   }`
3. Inherit your activity, fragment from `LinkedInManagerResponse`

   `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LinkedInManagerResponse`
4. Initiate the `LinkedInRequestManager` object instance for login process

   `LinkedInRequestManager linkedInRequestManager = new LinkedInRequestManager(Activity, LinkedInManagerResponse, "CLIENT ID", "CLIENT SECRET", "REDIRECTION URL");`
5. Start Authenticate with below statement

`linkedInRequestManager.showAuthenticateView(LinkedInRequestManager.MODE_BOTH_OPTIONS);`

*Available Modes*

```
LinkedInRequestManager.MODE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_ONLY
LinkedInRequestManager.MODE_LITE_PROFILE_ONLY
LinkedInRequestManager.MODE_BOTH_OPTIONS
```